# Dot Net Web App database operation happens synchronously(When ran locally), but it is Async when deployed to IIS server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, iis-6

I am new to Dot Net development, but i am stuck at one problem where everything works well locally, but when we publish it and deploy to cloud(Which is using IIS), when we call one API - It does not wait for database operations to complete and returns null. Any idea on what configurations i should change in IIS server to make this work?

```
[Route("days/{id}")]
public String days(Int32 id)
{
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                Day day = null;
                command.CommandText = @"
                    SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        [dbo].[Days_View]
                    WHERE
                        [Id] = @Id
                ";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                command.Connection = con;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet dayDS = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dayDS);
                using (DataSet dataset = invoiceDS)
                {
                    if (dataset.Tables.Count > 0 && dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        day = DataParser.Parse(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]);
                    }
                }
                DayViewModel viewModel = new DayViewModel
                {
                    Day = day
                };
                return this.ViewAsString(viewModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give some code example of what are you doing, for example an API call?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic Thank you for your response. Have added a sample code. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: command.Connection = con; from where you are getting con value?

Comment: 1. Is any exception thrown? It is a good practice to return an HTTP status code (5xx) to indicate an error (rather than returning the exception as a string).
2. Can you verify that the request actually gets to the SQL server?